# Работа с файлами. Выделение предложения

Tags: c++

Всем здравствуйте. 
С помощью текстового редактора Блокнот создать файл. Написать программу, которая выводит содержимое файла на экран.
Выделение фрагмента в тексте выделить произвольными символами (звездочками, слэшем и т.п)
Задание:
Определить количество повествовательных предложений в тексте; по нажатию произвольной клавиши выделить третье повествовательное предложение. 
Все пункты выполнил, кроме выделения 3 повествовательного. Пытаясь додуматься, как сделать так, чтобы программа записывала определенное предложения в переменную, сломал себе голову, так что очень надеюсь на помощь)
Ниже сама программа.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale (0,"rus");
FILE *f;
char pre[2] = ".";
int pred=0, b;
char ch;

f = fopen("File.txt","r");
while(!feof(f)){
    fscanf(f, "%c", &ch);
    cout<<ch;
}
if ((f = fopen("File.txt","r"))== NULL)
{
    printf("Невозможно открыть файл.\n");
    return 0;
}

while (!feof(f))
{   
    ch = fgetc(f);
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    if (ch == pre[i])
    {       
        pred++;
        break;
    }
}
fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
printf("\nКоличество повествовательных предложений : %i",pred);
fclose(f);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Брр... И что вы делаете - в смысле, как вы его находите? По исходникам совершенно непонятно, особенно что вы собираетесь делать тут - `for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    if (ch == pre[i])`, если `pre` - массив из двух символов, причем второй - нулевой...

Comment: Файл читаете посимвольно, а лучше построчно читать...

Comment: Я не понел что значит выделить предложение символом

Comment: Исходник программы, это не нахождение 3 предложения. Это подсчёт повествовательных. А вот выделение 3 повествовательного у меня не получилось, именно поэтому я и обратился к вам. Исходник был кинут, для общего понимания картины.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как все предложения заканчиваются точкой, и вам нужны предложения, а не символы, то и нужно читать строку до точки, а не читать символы(буфер).

```
vector<string> offers;
    string s;
    // пусть вы отмечали звездочкой повествовательные предложения
    char c = '*';
    // читаем все предложения из файла и  отмеченные добавляем в вектор
    while (getline(f, s, '.')) {
        // тут я не знаю , на каком месте вы отметили звездочкой предложение         
        if(s.find(c) != string::npos)
            offers.emplace_back(s);
    }
    cout << "Количество повествовательных предложений:\n" <<  offers.size() << endl;
    getchar(); // вводим любой символ и получаем  ответ на второй вопрос
    cout  <<"третье повествовательное предложение:\n" << offers[2];
```

Может я не правильно понел условие задачи, но это уже детали, не мешающие тому, как нужно подойти к решению задачи...

Comment: AR Hovsepyan. Вашу идею понял. Реализовать попробую, т. к. вектора - это не то, что мне нужно. Да и половину функций из тех, что вы исп. я вижу впервые) Но читать по строкам идея хорошая. Спасибо вам)

Comment: Не хотите вектор, используйте другую последовательность, это не имеет значения, но а функции  это  стандартные функции  ввода и  функция поиска для  строковых обьектов. А если ответ вам  полезен, просто нужно отмечать как полезный...